# How to combine entities from xml with the help of RxJava?

Tags: java, xml, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have 6 xml files which are presenting the same entities, but in different languages. I need to merge them into a single xml document, from, for example, such view:

document in enlish:

```
<persons lang="en">
    <person>
        <id>22</id>
        <name>John</name>
        <job>intern</job>
        ...
    </person>
    ...
</persons>
```

document in russian:

```
<persons lang="ru">
    <person>
        <id>22</id>
        <name>Джон</name>
        <job>стажёр</job>
        ...
    </person>
    ...
</persons>
```

to such:

```
<persons>
    <person>
        <id>22</id>
        <names>
            <name lang="en">John</name>
            <name lang="ru">Джон</name>
            ...
        </names>
        <jobs>
            <job lang="en">intern</job>
            <job lang="ru">стажёр</job>
            ...
        </jobs>
        ...
    </person>
    ...
</persons>
```

So, when I open this files like 6 Observable sources, what is the best way to combine the Observable streams to get entities from each file to get them together? All entities in different languages has same ids, could be this can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would *.concat()* all the source observables and apply *.reduce()* to the whole chain. See http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#reduce-R-rx.functions.Func2-

Answer (score 0):

First I would go for a more conservative - and versioned - format.
Instead of replacing `name` with `names/name/@lang` and `jobs` likewise, do

```
<persons version="1.1">
    <name>
        <ts>
            <t lang="en">John</t>
            <t lang="ru">Джон</t>
            ...
        </ts>
    </name>
    <job>
        <ts>
            <t lang="en">intern</t>
            <t lang="ru">стажёр</t>
            ...
        </ts>
    </job>
```

This allows text found in an old xml in `<name>` and `<job>` to wrap in a `<t lang="/persons@lang">`.

Oddly, probably due to my lack of intensive production experience with RxJava I would not try to do all with RxJava. For instance job names in several languages would be something for a dictionary (with synonyms & their frequency).